# Buying same product simultaneously in drupal commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

Case: There is a product in stock with 1 quantity. Now two or more buyers try to buy that product simultaneously.

I want to restrict any one from buying that product on first come first serve basis.

Is there any hook available ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom module. like

1. custom_module.info
2. custom_module.module

### and write this code in module file.

```
// form alter
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
    if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout'){       
        $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][] = 'paypal_check_handler';        
    }
}
// form handler
function paypal_check_handler(&$form, $form_state){    
    $order_number = $form_state['order']->order_number;
    $return = _get_current_stock($order_number);    
    if($return=='goto_paypal'){
        db_query("UPDATE commerce_order SET status = 'checkout_payment' where order_id='$order_number'");        
     }else{   
       db_query("UPDATE commerce_order SET status = 'checkout_checkout' where order_id='$order_number'");
       drupal_set_message("Stock not available");
       drupal_goto('cart');    
    }       
}

/* To show items in cart on paypal window closed*/
function custom_module_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter(&$checkout_pages) {
  $checkout_pages['payment']['status_cart'] = TRUE;
}
/**
 * This function check current stock.
 */
function _get_current_stock($order_id) {

    global $user;
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid); // get user order details


    // get all product id of current order
    $results = db_query("SELECT cp.product_id AS product_id, cli.quantity AS order_qty,fcs.commerce_stock_value AS stock_qty FROM commerce_line_item AS cli LEFT JOIN commerce_product AS cp ON cli.line_item_label=cp.sku LEFT JOIN field_data_commerce_stock AS fcs ON cp.product_id=fcs.entity_id WHERE cli.order_id='$order_id' AND cli.type ='product' ")->fetchAll();

    $product_ids = $qty = $stock_qty = array();
    /*
     * @var $product_ids            : Product ID array.
     * @var $qty[$product_ids]      : get each Product order quantity.
     * @var $stock_qty[$product_ids]: get each Product stock quantity.
     */
    foreach($results As $value){
        if(!empty($value->product_id)){
            $product_ids[] = $value->product_id;
            $qty[$value->product_id] = (int)$value->order_qty;
            $stock_qty[$value->product_id] = (int)$value->stock_qty;
        }
    }
    // product id array convert in string forn sql.
    $product_ids_query = implode($product_ids, ',');
    /*
     * Here get product remaining stock
     * @stock   : Stock
     * @order   : Order qty in order table ( status is checkout_payment).
     * @avail   : available qty
     * @stock - @order = @avail
     */
    $results2 = db_query("SELECT cli.line_item_label AS line_item, cp.product_id AS product_id,cli.quantity AS order_qty, FORMAT(SUM(cli.quantity),0) total_order_qty,  FORMAT(fcs.commerce_stock_value,0) AS total_stock_qty, FORMAT((fcs.commerce_stock_value - SUM(cli.quantity)),0) As available_qty FROM commerce_line_item AS cli LEFT JOIN commerce_product AS cp ON cli.line_item_label=cp.sku LEFT JOIN field_data_commerce_stock AS fcs ON cp.product_id=fcs.entity_id LEFT JOIN commerce_order AS co ON co.order_id=cli.order_id WHERE co.`status`='checkout_payment' AND fcs.commerce_stock_value!=0 AND cp.product_id IN ($product_ids_query) GROUP BY cp.product_id")->fetchAll();

    $available_qty = array();
    foreach($results2 As $value2){
        $available_qty[$value2->product_id] = $value2->available_qty;
    }
    $redirection_var = 'goto_paypal';
    foreach($product_ids AS $product_chk){
        if(!empty($available_qty[$product_chk])){
            $current_stock_qty = (int)$available_qty[$product_chk]; 
        } else {
            $current_stock_qty = (int)$stock_qty[$product_chk];
        }

        $ordered_qty = $qty[$product_chk];

        if($current_stock_qty > 0){
            // go to paypal
             $redirection_var;
        } else {
            return $redirection_var = 'not_goto_paypal';
        }
    }
    return $redirection_var;
}
```

Comment: Thank you...exactly what I was looking for. This will surely help others.

Comment: This code isn't using sanitized query variables. At least update your code to use placeholders  - https://www.drupal.org/node/310072

Answer (score 0):

Check out Commerce Stock - https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock. The module itself will expose hooks for controlling stock. Or there are sub modules it provides - Simple Stock and Simple Stock Rules - which add an integer field and use Rules to validate purchases.

This runs on Add to Cart, Can Checkout, and prior to purchase.